# Compile time operators and runtime ooerators in C

Tags: c, operator-overloading, operators

I just want to know any operators in C does their operations in compile time or in run time??

Or there are some operators which operates on the operands on compile time and some operators operates on run time?

Comment: Please don't spam unrelated language tags. If you have a question about C, then there is no reason for tagging java and python .

Comment: Why foo+bar can't be evaluated in run time?

Comment: The `sizeof` operator is a compile-time **only** operator. I *think* the unary `&` could be called a run-time only operator.

Comment: They can be evaluated at runtime. They cannot be evaluated at compile time as the values are not known

Comment: Operators used in preprocessor directives can only be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: @AdrianMole: `sizeof VLA` is a runtime operation.

Comment: @pmg Good catch! How about `_Alignof`, then?

Comment: @AdrianMole, `_Alignof` is compilation time because the alignment of an array (including VLA) is the same as alignment of an element of the array. It applies recursively until the compilation defined type is met.

Answer (score 0):

Expressions that can be evaluated during compiler time are evaluated at compile time (at least that's what modern compilers do).

Expressions that cannot be evaluated during compile time are evaluated at run time. This is totally independent of the type of operators.

Example:

```
void somefunction(int foo, int bar)
{
  printf("foo + bar = %d\n", foo + bar);
}
```

Here `foo + bar` cannot be evaluated at compile time because the values of `foo` and `bar` depend on the code that calls `somefunction`. It can only be evaluated at run time.

---

```
void someotherfunction(void)
{
  printf("1 + 2 = %d\n", 1 + 2);
}
```

Here `1 + 2` can be evaluated during compile time because `1 + 2` is always 3 by definition.

---

And here is a simple case where the compile ***may*** evaluate an expression containing variables even at compile time because the compiler can know that at the line `printf("%d", foo + bar);` `foo` is always 2 and `bar` is always 3 and therefore it can optimize the code and do the evaluation at compile time, even for variables.

```
void MyFunction()
{
  int foo = 2;
  int bar = 3;

  printf("%d", foo + bar);
  ...
}
```

Comment: So if I write :- int main(){ int a=10; int b=2; int c=a+b; return 0} , this code will evaluate 12 in c variable at compile time??

Comment: @mainakmukherjee maybe, or maybe not. It's up to the compiler.

Comment: @mainakmukherjee - Also, if you don't use the `c` value, the compiler might skip the evaluation altogether.